# How to build SEO urls in Rails 3.x with lots of optional URL params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, routes

Ok, I'm trying to make my urls seo friendly and get a little more indexing juice from google.  Basically, I have some urls that look like this:

> /articles?page=2&filter=all

and I want it to look like this

> /articles/all/2

I've got the /artiles/:filter/:page part to work just fine as I did my routes like this:

```
resources: :articles do
  get '(:filter(/:page)', action: :index, on: :collection
end
```

My question is how do I get the page param to work without the filter (or other optional params)?

> /articles/?page=2

should look like

> /articles/2

I've been thinking of using contraints but can't seem to get it to work, something along the lines of this

```
resources: :articles do
  get ':page', action: :index, on: :collection, constraints: { page: /\d+/ }  
  get '(:filter(/:page)', action: :index, on: :collection
end
```

**EDIT**

I didn't realize it but the above works, what doesn't is the link_to is not generating the pretty urls.  e.g. /articles/all/1, it's still outputting /articles?filter=all.  This is the link_to code I'm using:

```
= link_to "Filter", articles_path(filter: 'all') #=> /articles?filter=all
```

and I want: /articles/all and /articles/all/2 and /articles/2 and to all work.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to create 'articles/2/all' and then make filter optional.

Comment: I need it both ways (/articles/all and /articles/2 and /articles/all/2) but it actually works the way I set it up, I actually just need to configure the link_to to create the correct url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add the word "page" to the URL so the routing helper knows it's calling a page and not passing a filter name:

```
/articles/page/1
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  get 'page/:page', action: "index", on: :collection, constraints: { page: /\d+/ }, as: :articles_with_page
  get ':filter/page/:page', action: :index, on: :collection, as: :articles
end
```

The brackets mean that that part of the route name is optional. Since in you're case you're being quite specific about the pattern it should match, It'd remove them.

Also, you've called the filter namespace `:articles` - that will clash with the default index route so you should either rename it or pass `except: [:index]` to the resources block:

```
resources except: [:index] do
  # stuff here
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Just did this with some small tweaks and worked great, already indexed in google for all the missing pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but it might put you in the right direction.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def articles_with_optional_page_path(params)
    if params[:page] && !!params[:filter]
      articles_with_page_path(params)
    else
      articles_path(params)
    end
  end
end

resources: :articles do
  get ':page', action: :index, on: :collection, constraints: { page: /\d+/ }, as: :articles_with_page
  get '(:filter(/:page)', action: :index, on: :collection, as: :articles
end
```

Comment: This kinda helped just naming the route with an as: worked for some but my kaminari links aren't working the way I want them to.